# Setting stack-size ulimit for mongodb to reduce connection overhead

Tags: mongodb, connections

I am using MongDB 2.4.9 and working on performance tunung. With reference to the ulimit settings for mongodb, in my linux environment (ubuntu 12.04) the default setting for ulimit -s is 8192. MongoDB does not specify any default value for ulimit -s (stack-size). However [this case study](https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-connection-overhead/) suggests to set stack-size to 1024. How does the default stack-size 8291 impacts mongodb performance. Does changing this value to 1024 help to reduce connection per overhead in order to improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default stack size for MongoDB is already 1024, not 8192 (it is set in the code, not as a system setting) and has been since version 1.8.3 (see [SERVER-2707](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2707)), so you are already seeing the benefits of a lower stack size.